# Dictionnary item with `.` in index

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I have this dictionnary

```
# Views.py

results = {}
# Set content types
results["teams.team"] = []
results["users.userprofile"] = []

for result in sqs:
    content_type = result.content_type() # teams.team , users.userprofile, ... 
    results[content_type].append(result.get_additional_fields()) # get_additional_fields => {title:"" , ... }
```

How can I display teams.team size in a django template ?
I have tried `{{ results.user.userprofile.count }}` but it seems that `.` are making wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: You mean you want to get the length of the list in `"teams.team"`?

Comment: Yes, but only in the template, and `{{ results['users.userprofile'].count` gives `Could not parse the remainder` error

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary should use `:` not `=` as follows:

```
results = {
    "user.userprofile": {
         "title": "the name"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
{{ results['user.userprofile']['title'] }}
```

Answer to your updated question:

```
{{ len(results['teams.team']) }}
```

Comment: The dictionnay is only here for people can see data structure, it is not like that in my code ;)

Comment: @FabienPapet, What do you mean? Dictionaries are as follows: {key:value, key:value}. If you change your dictionary to how I have shown, it will work with my answer.

Comment: I agree, what i mean is that I don't  define a dictionnary manually in my code

Comment: @FabienPapet, Then your dictionary probably has the right format, Try running the code and see if it works.

Comment: @FabienPapet, Please see my updated answer to your updated question. You can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51177/discussion-between-fabien-papet-and-sshashank124)